# Configure Windows 7 to find executable without .exe

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to configure Windows 7 to execute plink.exe when I just type plink (without the .exe")?
Right now, when I type 'plink', it said command not found. But when I type 'plink.exe', it finds it.

Comment: Is Plink.exe in the folder you are in when trying to run it?  If not, then you probably have another executable named "Plink" in your path ahead of where the Plink.exe file sits, which is interfering.

Answer (score 2):

By execute plink, I assume you mean when you type in "plink" in the Start Menu -> Search bar.

What gets run in there is stuff in the environment variable PATH. If plink.exe is not in your current PATH, you can go to System Properties (Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced tab -> Environment Variables button) and adjust the System Path variable.
[image: System Properties for Windows 7]
[image: Environment Variables for Windows 7]

Or you could just copy plink to C:\Windows\System32\ because it's easier.

### Running plink from command line

To run plink from the command line, again, it has to be in the present working directory or in your PATH. You can set PATH from the cli:

set path=%path%;c:\directory\of\plink\

Comment: I doubt if this will solve problem